# More nested while loops in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, nested

I tried to pull some data from database but i need two while loops to nest (fetch_assoc). The problem is that the inner loop doesn't loop it just gives me the first element of array, array length times.

```
<?php
    $al_num = $_GET['album'];
    $photo_query = "SELECT photo FROM album WHERE album_number={$al_num}";
    $thumbnail_query = "SELECT thumbnail FROM album WHERE album_number={$al_num}";

    $photo_result = mysqli_query($connection, $photo_query);
    $thumbnail_result = mysqli_query($connection, $thumbnail_query);
?>




<?php while($photo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($photo_result)): ?>
    <?php while($thumb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($thumbnail_result)): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="images/<?php echo $photo['photo'] ?>" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
            <img src="images/<?php echo $thumb['thumbnail'] ?>"  alt=""/>
            </a>
        </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have more than one record in `thumbnail` table? Just don't do it like this. There are serious security issues in your code. You can process your images and thumbnails on database layer with joins, this is pointless solution.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in data architecture. How do you save many thumbnails and many photos for a certain album? Don't you need a set of photos and just one thumbnail for every album?

Comment: I have same number of thumbnails and photos in my database table in table i have album number (al_num), photo name and thumb name.

Comment: This is page where i list images of specific album it's just an int in table. I have array with names of albums in page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to keep it simple?

```
<?php
    $al_num = $_GET['album'];
    // Really good idea to check the $_GET['album'] first ...
    $photo_query = "SELECT photo, thumbnail FROM album WHERE album_number='".mysqli_real_escape_string ($connection, $al_num)."'";
    $photo_result = mysqli_query($connection, $photo_query);

    while(list ($photo, $thumb) = mysqli_fetch_row ($photo_result)) {
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="images/<?php echo $photo ?>" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
            <img src="images/<?php echo $thumb ?>"  alt=""/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: I got this: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/mirko/Dropbox/htdocs/pdc/gallery.php on line 63

Comment: Right, I added $connection in mysqli_real_escape_string. Check the code above.

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/mirko/Dropbox/htdocs/pdc/galerija.php on line 73

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/mirko/Dropbox/htdocs/pdc/galerija.php on line 73

Line 73 is where while loop starts

Comment: I got it working, thanks a lot. I didn't changed assoc to row. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try fetching from both tables inside one 'while' loop only here's how you will do it

```
<?php while($photo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($photo_result) || $thumb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($thumbnail_result))
{ ?>

        <li>
            <a href="images/<?php echo $photo['photo'] ?>" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
            <img src="images/<?php echo $thumb['thumbnail'] ?>"  alt=""/>
            </a>
        </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I tried this way but then i get double number of images half without link part (name of file)